# Using Boolean Difference for Imported 3D Scans

Tags: modifiers, import

I am interested in obtaining the resulting mesh that deletes the differences between two aligned meshes (block 1 and block 2; see attached images).
Both objects were scanned using a 3D scanner and are water-tight (no holes). They were then imported into Blender as .stl files and appear to be perfectly registered according to their geometry. I then select block 1 as my target mesh and block 2 as the object. I select the 'Boolean difference' option and the 'carve' option as the type of solver. However, Blender seems to be unable to accurately determine the difference between the two meshes. Is anyone able to provide suggestions on why this boolean is failing?[image][image]

Comment: I guess the base shape is identical in both "blocks": boolean doesn't work well when the two mesh share some identical end perfectly aligned geometry, afaik. if you're trying to get only the smaller shape laid above the base shape, you could probably do that without booleans...

Comment: It may also happen that the scanned surfaces are too high resolution and too dense to successfully calculate a boolean operation.

Comment: Did you tried [meshmixer](http://www.meshmixer.com/)?